# reset page elements to empty when changing page in Taipy

Tags: taipy

Currently to reset the page variables and elements I use,

```
def refresh_project_part(state):
    state.name = None
    state.description = None
    state.p_name = None
    state.p_description = None
    state.cad_filepath= None
```

But this hinders the page response time. and there is a delay every time I navigate between pages. is it possible to refresh the page somehow?

Comment: Could you describe your ideal solution? What is your use case for the navigation between pages?

Comment: I have multiple forms that help me create projects and navigate through data storage. These are distributed across multiple pages and this variable refresh would help me for example, when I create a new project and it's successful. it should reset the variable values to empty or None. Similarly, if I fill the form halfway through and switch tabs the page elements should not keep the filled-in details when I navigate back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are no easy way to reinitialize certain elements of a Gui after navigating to a page.

I would suggest creating a dictionary with all the fields of your form and to reinitialize it after saving your form.

Markdown syntax:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify


form = {"Name":"",
        "Email":"",
        "Phone":""}

md = """
<|{form.Name}|input|>

<|{form.Email}|input|>

<|{form.Phone}|input|>

<|Submit|button|on_action=save|>
"""

def save(state):
    notify(state, "success", "Saved!")
    state.form = {key:"" for key in form.keys()} 

Gui(md).run()
```

Page Builder:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui, notify
import taipy.gui.builder as tgb

form = {"Name":"",
        "Email":"",
        "Phone":""}

def save(state):
    notify(state, "success", "Saved!")
    state.form = {key:"" for key in form.keys()} 

with tgb.Page() as page:
    for key in form:
        tgb.input('{form.'+key+'}', label=key)

    tgb.button("Submit", on_action=save)


Gui(page).run()
```

[image: GUI Result]

Does that solve your issue?